# Is procedure turn considered published approach course?

Tags: approach, aeronautical-charts

Procedure turn is not completely lined on the chart and only marked with the barbed arrow. Is it still considered a segment of a published approach course? Can you report to ATC that you're established on the course when you're flying PT?

Comment: Jepp or Gov't chart? Could you provide example of the chart, or the name of the approach, and I'll attach it for you.

Comment: I think both charts use the barbed wire to mark standard PT.

Comment: I've only used Gov't charts. I'm not familiar with that term "barbed wire" as it relates to plates. I'd like to see what it looks like, maybe I just think of it as something else. Do you have an approach name, like an ILS or VOR etc and name of airport that I can go look up?

Comment: Sorry. I think the proper name is barbed arrow not barbed wire. My apologies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’ve been doing a lot of practice approaches lately and if a procedure turn (or hold) is required, they tell me to 'report procedure turn (hold) inbound'. Then they clear me for the approach. I think this is why:

**AIM 5−4−7. Instrument Approach Procedures**

> b. When operating on an unpublished route or **while being radar vectored**, the pilot, when an approach clearance is received, must, in addition to complying with the minimum altitudes for IFR operations (14 CFR Section 91.177), maintain the last assigned altitude unless a different altitude is assigned by ATC, or until the aircraft is established on a segment of a published route or IAP. After the aircraft is so established, published altitudes apply to descent within each succeeding route or approach segment unless a different altitude is assigned by ATC. Notwithstanding this pilot responsibility, for aircraft operating on unpublished routes or while being radar vectored, **ATC will, except when conducting a radar approach, issue an IFR approach clearance only after the aircraft is established on a segment of a published route** or IAP, or assign an altitude to maintain until the aircraft is established on a segment of a published route or instrument approach procedure. **For this purpose, the procedure turn of a published IAP must not be considered a segment of that IAP until the aircraft reaches the initial fix or navigation facility upon which the procedure turn is predicated.**